# Word: VBA recorded macro gives runtime error

Tags: vba, windows, ms-word

I have a daily task two or three very simple word docs, I do a mail merge to send the docs to addresses from Excel. Very simple Mailings, Start mail merge - Email, select data source- xlsm file, clean up act and send. Verry very simple. However, a single button click would be easier!! Recorded a vba macro of the operation. After completion of recording, Clicked the button to start the macro, received this run time error: "by mail or fax
without a valid mail address. Choose the Setup button to select a mail
address data field." Tried several times, What is causing the error, how to fix?  Highlighted step on error: "Execute Pause:=False" Code from recording :

```
Sub sendMailSheet1()
'
' sendMail Macro
'
'
'MsgBox "In Sheets1"
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdEMail
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        "C:\Users\Hal 1GB M2\Documents\MyEmailer.xlsm", ConfirmConversions:=False _
        , ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:= _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\Hal 1GB M2\Documents\MyEmailer.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Lo" _
        , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
        wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToEmail
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge to email needs to know which field/column in the Data Source contains the email address it should use to send each email.

The macro recorder does not record the line of code needed for that. (The macro recorder can be a useful starting point but it doesn't record everything). After the line `.Destination = wdSendToEmail` you need something like

```
    .MailAddressFieldName = "email"
```

Where email is the exact name of the Excel column (it's case-sensitive) containing the e-address.

You may also need

```
    .MailFormat = wdMailFormatHTML ' or wdMailFormatPlainText
    .MailSubject = "the text you want as the subject of every email"
```

Comment: I did add the other two lines. However,  I get the same error. the format is only one column of data, "A". Cell A1 contains "EmailTo". Which I used for the above Address. Do I need to tell it, hesding in row  one, data does not start until row two? I would like to give the up vote, but it does not work. Although I believe you gave me good solid comments.

Comment: Also, in the last line of the SQL in has "SubType:= _
        wdMergeSubTypeAccess" Should that maybe be "Excel"?

Comment: @HalEgbert Can you spell out what you mean by "the format is only one column of data" ? From your description, you should be using .MailAddressFieldName = "EmailTo" (and not, e.g. = "emailto". In the current version of Windows Word, you should be able to reduce your OpenDataSource to thisActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        "C:\Users\Hal 1GB M2\Documents\MyEmailer.xlsm"  , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"

Comment: @HalEgbert i.e. you shouldn't need the the Connection parameter *at all*. By default, Word should in fact cooose the "HDR=Yes" option that assumes your Excel sheet's first row contains column names. Yes, it looks as if you might have to change the subtype to Excel rather than Access, but in fact you shouldn't need the subtype either (it's a relic, and when Word uses OLEDB to get data from Excel, it's actually using the Access Jet provider to do it, hence the "Access" in the value of that parameter.).

Comment: @HalEgbert If your manual connection is working, but the programmatic connection does not, then there must be a problem I haven't been able to spot yet. (i.e. the set-up I have here that tries to duplicate your scenario works OK)

Comment: @HalEgbert BTW the backticks surrounding "Sheet1$" have been removed from my comment You need those, or you should be able to use SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] instead.

Comment: @HalEgbert Just one more thing that occurs to me that I haven't just re-tested. Is your .xslm *already open* in Excel or not?

Comment: The excel program is not running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255959/discussion-between-hal-egbert-and-jonsson).

Comment: Simple format, only one column of data. Col A Cell A1 Is EmailTo, Cells 2 thur 4 are email addresses in the from od Name<Nane@domain.com>. No other data.

Comment: 63 bit windows 10, all current on updates. MS365 pro

Comment: I guess, you know I don't have 63 bit windows!! , 64 bit. I systematically inserted everything you gave. SUCCESS It works, I now have the single button click for my mail merge I wanted. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad you got there, even on a 63-bit system :-) always  a mystery if the "obvious things" don't seem to work. Anyway, I'll be deleting most of my comments in due course.